# PCB Board design questions

Tags: pcb-design

I want to design a PCB board computer that is very similar to a raspberry pi or an Orange Pi. It needs to have no ports aside from Ethernet. It should plug directly into an electrical outlet and have have another electrical outlet on the other side of it that can works just like a normal port outlet. On the board I want to have a switch that cuts off the power to the other power outlet but the computer is still powered.

Would this be expensive to manufacture?

Would it be expensive to hire someone to design it for me?

sorry if this may be off topic, but if you could point me in a direction where I can learn more please do :)

Comment: Why do you need a full computer instead of a microcontroller?

Comment: Because I would need to do some somewhat advanced networking  security things with it, so it would need to function like any old computer. Also, I want to program it in python and allow users to set up the device with SSH.

Comment: What do you consider "expensive" ? I often find this to be true: if you have to ask what it costs then probably you cannot afford it. Why not use an Rpi or Opi and only make an additional board with the mains switching and the Ethernet stuff (assuming that would even be needed).

Comment: I would be willing to pay a designer upwards of $1500 and ideally less than $30 per unit to manufacture in bulk. I really have no idea how much this type of thing costs and this is part of my research. To anwser your second question, that hadn't crossed my mind. Thank you :) I'm more of a programmer than an electrical engineer.

Comment: $1500 is less than two days. I don't think that is enough time to do the job. Not if you need full schematic and layout. I am ignoring "bulk" because I doubt you could sell more than 100 of these. So the $30 also probably cannot be realized. If you can sell 100,000 units, then you can maybe get a bulk price. Injection molded plastic tooling is also way more expensive than you probably think. Even a small part will have thousands of dollars of tooling cost. And you will need a lot of compliance tests to be done. I think there is much more NRE than you expect.

Comment: Do you have a working prototype already ? It will be a lot easier and less risky (saving money) to go to a custom design if you already have working hardware. I'm thinking an Rpi or Opi board with an additional PCB with the special hardware you need.

Comment: I think I will do your idea of having a separate board. To be honest, I think that my current prototype is a major fire hazard because I am bad at wiring. How would I power the PI if I don't have it on the same board?

Comment: *How would I power the PI if I don't have it on the same board?* By just using a standard AC adapter (USB charger). Not sure why this would be an issue/challenge.

Comment: @mkeith "$1500 is less than two days" That amount varies a lot, depending on the country the consultant/designer is in. I, for example, living in Eastern Europe, would be willing to work for two weeks for that money. On the other hand, I agree that $30 per unit is not a realistic goal.

Comment: @eliasbothell Before you go and throw money out the window, do some research to see if your idea isn't already implemented and available on the market at a low price. You might think you came up with an original product idea, but later find out that someone else is already doing that..

Comment: @m.Alin, yes, for sure. Highly qualified talent is also available in lower cost areas. It depends somewhat on where the OP is located and whether the OP is willing to work with someone who is not local. I may have been hasty, but based on various subtle signs, assumed that the OP is in the US.

Comment: I am in the US and I do intend to work with a remote designer.

Comment: Even if you are able to hire a designer for that little ($1500), you'll have to spend far more than that on parts (Probably >$1000 for NRE alone, plus another >$200 **per board** for fab and assembly, plus shipping). Not to mention you probably won't have much of a market, so breaking even would be practically impossible. You'd have to figure out a way to make it much more appealing to the masses and make it much more cost-effective. You're most definitely not going to get it done any time soon. This sort of thing is probably going to take at least a year of research and development alone.

Answer (score 1):

You start off by buying a few mains networking widgets with through sockets, something like the BT Broadband Extender Flex 1000 kit (other fine networking products are available), which sounds like it has most of the features you are after.

Then you pull one apart, and find out what it is built from, and why it costs what it does. You operate another, to see what it does 'as is'. You hack a third, install linux on it, add a relay for the mains output etc. That's called research.

Thus informed, you can then go to a design house with real specifications and a stab at a bill of materials.